How to use seeder for related tables
Im in laravel 11. I need to add some kind of specific mock data.
There is a table with countries (id, name) and a table with cities (id, country_id, name).
So doing it with seeder I do this:
CountrySeeder.php

DB::table('country')->insert(['name' => 'US']);
DB::table('country')->insert(['name' => 'UK']);

CitySeeder.php

DB::table('city')->insert(['name' => 'NY', 'country_id' => 1]);
DB::table('city')->insert(['name' => 'LA', 'country_id' => 1]);
DB::table('city')->insert(['name' => 'London', 'country_id' => 2]);

This looks cheap and ugly to me. I would prefer to have some kind of mechanism to get data in a better way without the seeder needing to know about the ID of a specific country. Maybe having some kind of json file with data that can easily get picked up. I wonder how you people do this when working with laravel seeders.

First of all, you are not required to use Fluent, but can use Eloquent instead in a seeder. Also, you should never guess or assume ids of new entries. Depending on the state of the database, an id does not have to start at 1. If you had data in the table before and truncated it without resetting the AUTO_INCREMENT, the id for the first entry will start where the old entries left off instead.
You could then simply write a seeder for a structure like that like this:
class CountrySeeder extends Seeder
{
    protected array $countriesWithCities = [
        'US' => ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Phoenix', 'Philadelphia', 'San Antonio', 'San Diego', 'Dallas', 'San Jose'],
        'UK' => ['London', 'Birmingham', 'Leeds', 'Glasgow', 'Sheffield', 'Bradford', 'Liverpool', 'Edinburgh', 'Manchester', 'Bristol'],
    ];


    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->countriesWithCities as $country => $cities) {
            $country = Country::create(['name' => $country]);

            $country->Cities()->createMany(
                array_map(
                    fn($city) => ['name' => $city], 
                    $cities
                )
            );
        }
    }
}

This assumes that you have created Country and City models beforehand, and that the Country model has a relationship called Cities that would be a HasMany relationship to City::class. Also, name would have to be in the $fillable array for both models.
Using the array gives you the benefit of better readability and maintainability of the data.
